# Acceder a una struct de una union con un nodo auxiliar

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy tratando de hacer una lista enlazada de clientes y veterinarios, con distintos tipos de datos, e hice una union de dos struct para usarlos como el tipo de dato del nodo, pero nose como acceder a ellos desde un nodo auxiliar para la funcion add(), y en algunos datos tipos de string me salen errores como **no operator "=" matches operands -- operand types are std::string = std::string**.
Este es mi archivo header para definir los datos y funciones:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using std::string;
#ifndef DEF_H
#define DEF_H
union personas{
    struct  {
        string nombre_persona;
        string apellido_paterno;
        string apellido_materno;
        int firsteight;
        char verifydigit;
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
        string nombre_animal;
        string raza;
        string especie;
        int ID;
    };
    struct {
        string nombre_persona;
        string apellido_paterno;
        string apellido_materno;
        int firsteight;
        char verifydigit;
        int day[];
        int month[];
        int year[];
        string especialidad;
        int num_pacientes;
    };
};
struct node{
    personas data;
    struct node*next;
};
struct list{    
    int _size;
    struct node *_head;
};
struct list *create();
struct list *add_cliente(struct list *,string,string,string,int,char,int,int,int,string,string,string,int);
struct list *add_back(struct list *,string,string,string,int,char,int,int,int,string,string,string,int);
struct list *remove(struct list *);
#endif
```

y la funcion que estoy tratando de implementar es añadir un cliente:

```
struct list *add_cliente(struct list *myList,string nombre[],string apellidop,string apellidom,int rutdigitos[],char verificador,int dia[],int mes,int anho,string nombreanimal[],string razaanimal,string especieanimal,int id){
    struct node *n_aux;
    n_aux->data.nombre_persona = nombre;
    n_aux->data.apellido_paterno=apellidop;
    n_aux->data.apellido_materno=apellidom;
    n_aux->data.firsteight=rutdigitos;
    n_aux->data.verifydigit=verificador;    
    n_aux->data.day=dia;
    n_aux->data.month=mes;
    n_aux->data.year=anho;
    n_aux->data.nombre_animal = nombreanimal;
    n_aux->data.raza=razaanimal;
    n_aux->data.especie=especieanimal;
    n_aux->data.ID=myList->_size;
    n_aux->next = myList->_head;
    myList->_head = n_aux;
    (myList->_size)+=1;
    return myList;
}
```

disculpen el spaghetti estoy aprendiendo

Answer (score 5):

Tu error no tiene nada que ver con el acceso a una estructura de una unión con un nodo auxiliar. Tu error está en la discrepancia entre la declaración de funciones y la definición de funciones:

```
// Declaración de 'add_cliente':
struct list *add_cliente(struct list *,string,string,string,int,char,int,int,int,string,string,string,int);
// Definición de 'add_cliente':
struct list *add_cliente(struct list *,string [],string,string,int [],char,int[],int,int ,string [],string,string,int)
```

Por si no queda claro, vamos a poner los parámetros lado a lado:

```
| Parámetro | Declaración | Definición |
+-----------+-------------+------------+
| 1         | list *      | list *     |
| 2         | string      | string[]   |
| 3         | string      | string     |
| 4         | string      | string     |
| 5         | int         | int[]      |
| 6         | char        | char       |
| 7         | int         | int[]      |
| 8         | int         | int        |
| 9         | int         | int        |
| 10        | string      | string[]   |
| 11        | string      | string     |
| 12        | string      | string     |
| 13        | int         | int        |
```

Cuando intentas asignar un `string[]` a un `string`, el compilador lógicamente se va a quejar.

---

Esto te ha pasado porque tu código es muy propenso a errores, difícil de leer, entender y mantener. Te aconsejo lo siguiente:

1. **NO** crees una estructura con dos uniones que comparten variables con nombres iguales, te será imposible distinguir entre los ocho primeros elementos de la primera estructura respecto a la segunda. Si son datos distintos, deben ir en objetos distintos.
2. Una función con 13 parámetros, como has podido ver, es muy propensa a ser confusa y difícil de entender y mantener. Si lo que quieres es almacenar un cliente, pásale el cliente en lugar de los parámetros de construcción.
3. En C++ las estructuras son tipos de primer orden, no se necesita anteponer `struct` para instanciarlas.

Comment: gracias por la observación, tomare tu consejo. en que situación recomiendas usar `template<>` para un nodo ?

Comment: @DavidGómezPinto esa es una pregunta muy interesante y creo que merece una publicación propia para poder dar una respuesta como se merece.